# Group join skip the first 10 items to print on second page or a method to jump to certain index

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want print a list of measurements(afmetingen) ordered by measure attribute you can measure it with(toestel). So i use group join to find all correct measurements on place it in groups of measure attributes. Now the first page is OK, but when i came at the end of the page (not enough space) i detect it and don't print the rest of it.

So i place the ev.getmorepages on true so it starts again on the second page. But i don't have to print the first 10 measurements. How to i skip the first 10 measurements?

The skip option doesn't work...

Now is there a way to start from a certain index at the list of measurements? of to skip the first 10 of it.

```
private void pd_PrintPageV2(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
                    var afmetinger =
                       from selectoestel in toestel
                       orderby selectoestel.Volgnr
                       where selectoestel.IDnumber >= meettoestel 
                       join metinger in tempmeetrapport.afmetingen on selectoestel.IDnumber equals metinger.meettoestel into metinggroup
                       select new
                        {
                            //select toestel naam
                            toestel = selectoestel.naam,
                            volgnr = selectoestel.IDnumber,
                            //select de volledig afmeting
                            afmetingers = from prod2 in metinggroup
                                          orderby prod2.nummer
                                          select prod2
                        };

         int i = 0;

         //code to print the measurement attribute on the page (deleted (to long))

         //start printing all measurements row by row
         foreach (var productGroup in afmetinger)
         {
             foreach (var prodItem in productGroup.afmetingers)
             {
                if(i < 10){ print something on page }
                i++

             }
            }

         // If more lines exist, print another page.
         if (i>10)
         {
             ev.HasMorePages = true;
         }    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select all items to a single list and use LINQ's `Skip` method:

```
var allItems = afmetinger.SelectMany(x => x.afmetingers);
foreach (var prodItem in allItems.Skip(numberOfItemsToSkip))
```

Also, if you always want to display just 10 items, you can combine it with `Take`:

```
foreach (var prodItem in allItems.Skip(numberOfItemsToSkip).Take(10))
```